# Unregister devices Aerogear

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, aerogear

I am implementing and Android application to send and receive push notifications using Aerogear and OpenShift.
I am having an issue to unregister the device, if I open the app and I register the device it works,I can send notifications and all works good, if I try to unregister the device also works well, my problem is when I close the app and my device is registered, if i relaunch the app and I want to unregister the devices i am getting this error:

"The server returned the error code 404"

07-11 21:07:32.436  21158-21245/? D/GCM﹕ GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER
07-11 21:07:32.606  20520-20520/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
07-11 21:07:32.606  20520-20520/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
07-11 21:07:32.606  20520-20520/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: survey data missing!

This is my actual code

```
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
try {
RegistrarManager.config(PUSH_REGISTER_NAME, AeroGearGCMPushConfiguration.class)
.setPushServerURI(new URI(UNIFIED_PUSH_URL))
.setSenderIds(GCM_SENDER_ID)
.setVariantID(VARIANT_ID)
.setSecret(SECRET)
.setAlias(ALIAS)
.setDeviceToken(ALIAS)
.asRegistrar();
PushRegistrar registrar = RegistrarManager.getRegistrar(PUSH_REGISTER_NAME);
registrar.register(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new Callback<Void>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void ignore) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   
@Override
public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
});
btnUnregister = (Button)mInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnUnregister);
btnUnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
try{
RegistrarManager.config(PUSH_REGISTER_NAME, AeroGearGCMPushConfiguration.class)
.setPushServerURI(new URI(UNIFIED_PUSH_URL))
.setSenderIds(GCM_SENDER_ID)
.setVariantID(VARIANT_ID)
.setSecret(SECRET)
.setAlias(ALIAS)
.setDeviceToken(ALIAS)
.asRegistrar();
PushRegistrar registrar = RegistrarManager.getRegistrar(PUSH_REGISTER_NAME);
registrar.unregister(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new Callback<Void>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void ignore) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
}catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
});
```

Any advice to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure it seems to be working for me (isn't it always the case).     

  One of the things that jumps out at me is that in your unregister block you don't need to set the configuration parameters again.  You can just all getRegister.  


  Do you happen to know what version of UPS and what version of the Android library you are using?  

  Double also, have you tried running UPS locally instead of on OpenShift?

Comment: I am using the version 2.2.0 and I have only tried using openshift, I also have tried the code in this link https://aerogear.org/docs/guides/aerogear-android/push/  and it works as long as you have the app opened if you close the app and after that you try to unregister i am getting a nullpointer exception becuase android does not find the registrar object to do "registrar.unregister(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<Void>()"

Comment: To get around the NPE stuff you should put the PushRegistrar.config things into the onCreate method of the Application object.  That way no matter what the objects will always be there.